# How to automatically call a method or generate code if a subclass derived from a base class?

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming

I have some classes that describe abilities / behaviours, such as flying, or driving etc. Each of these classes has a specific method that must be called to load some data - For example, Flyable has `loadFlyData()`, Drivable has `loadDriveData()`. For each class the method name is unique.

I have many derived classes that may inherit from one or more of these behaviour classes. Each of these derived classes has a method called `loadData()`, in which we should call all the parent behaviour classes methods such as `loadFlyData()`, `loadDriveData()` etc.... Is there a way to automatically generate this method using metaprogramming ? Since there are many derived classes, it may be more maintainable if I can generate these methods using metaprogramming...

Behaviour classes : (An object class may have any of these behaviours, and will have to call that classes "load" method...

```
class Flyable {
  void loadFlyData() {
  }
};

class Drivable{
  void loadDriveData() {
  }
};
```

All object classes derive from Object:

```
class Object {
  virtual void loadData() {
  }
};
```

A derived class:

```
class FlyingCar : public Object, public Flyable, public Drivable {
    virtual void loadData() override {
        // How to automatically generate code so that the next two lines are called:
        loadFlyData();
        loadDriveData();
  }
};
```

Comment: Can `loadFlyData()` and `loadDriveData` be of same name? such that they are only distinguished by scope, `Flyable::loadData()` and `Drivable::loadData()`? If so, then a template based approach to call each of the `T::loadData()` where T is a base class, should work. Though unsure how to get the base class list in the form of a variadic.

Comment: If all base-object use the same name for the "load" function (e.g. `loadData`) then it is possible to create a pre-processing step that takes the source file and modifies it. It might be possible using template meta-programming, but it will probably be more work than its worth (and your current solution will be less to write and more importantly easier to read and maintain). It is also possible do create code at run-time but that is much harder and will make it even less readable and maintainable. What you have now is simply the best and easiest solution.

Comment: Yes we can have the same name for loadFlyData and loadDriveData. The confusion for me (coming from a java background) is how to handle the conflict if they had the same name (thats why i used different names). The answers given below are  the kind of thing I am looking for (by storyteller and krzaq). I had no idea you could do these kinds of things in c++!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a free function `loadXData()` that will become a noop if your class isn't `X`:

```
namespace detail
{

void loadFlyData(Flyable* ptr) { ptr->loadFlyData(); }
void loadFlyData(...) {}

void loadDriveData(Drivable* ptr) { ptr->loadDriveData(); }
void loadDriveData(...) {}

}

class FlyingCar : public Object, public Flyable, public Drivable{
public:
    virtual void loadData()override{
        //How to automatically generate code so that the next two lines are called:
        detail::loadFlyData(this);
        detail::loadDriveData(this);
    }
};
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2gjQUabeJLIua2Sy)

Though I think using a common name `loadData` and just calling it for all variadic parents might be preferable:

```
template<typename... Policies>
struct ComposedType : Object, Policies...
{
    virtual void loadData() override {
        int arr[] = {
            ((void)Policies::loadData(), 0)...
        };
        (void)arr;
    }
};

using FlyingCar = ComposedType<Drivable, Flyable>;
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tPohPZJyqVjKINJd)

The above `loadData` could be simplified in C++1z:

```
virtual void loadData() override {
    ((void)Policies::loadData(), ...);
}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/T6hzojvoXfx9x0ch)

Comment: `((void)Policies::loadData(), 0)...` and the return type doesn't need to be modified. I learned something today :)

Comment: What is "(void)arr;" for ? What does it do ? Also, what if Flying car has additional behaviour that I wanted to add ? It seems to me that I should actually keep the most derived class, as not really having any behaviour of its own (just the using statement), and instead compose it of other behaviours....

Comment: Also, why do you have the 0, in ((voidPoliciens::loadData(),0)... ?

Comment: @john `(void)arr` is to keep the "unused variable" warning away in pre-C++17 compilers (where you have `[[maybe_unused]]`).

Comment: @John If you want special behaviour for `FlyingCar` then feel free to inherit from `ComposedType`, as in @StoryTeller's example

Comment: @John the pre-C++17 trick is that you initialize the array of integers `arr` with integers that depend on the pack expansion. But they need to be valid integers too, that's why I call `Policies::loadData()`, cast its result to void and then use the comma operator to discard the left hand side of the parenthesized expression and use `0` as the initializer.

Comment: Hmm, Is this not for C++11 ? I tried doing "template<typename... Policies>
class ComposedType : public Object,Policies...{", but at this line the compiler complains that "Base class 'Object' specified more than once as a direct base class.....but its specified just once....

Comment: @John I always inherit from `Object` in my example, there's no need to add it to the template parameter list

Comment: But, I need to inherit from Object.... Why is it complaining then ? Or perhaps I've misunderstood, In my code Object is actually called something else... lets say ObjectBR... why does it complain ? I'm inheriting just once...

Comment: if you have `ComposedType : Object, Policies...` and `ComposedType<Object,Drivable, Flyable>;`  (note that I added `Object` that isn't there in my example), then the pack gets expanded to `ComposedType: Object, Object, Drivable, Flyable` ⟵ `Object` is here twice.

Comment: Ah.... I found out the problem.... The compiler seems to read ahead, and indicates the error in the wrong... So even though a later ComposedType has Object in it,..... it complains at ComposedType:Object,Policies, even though it is mentioned just once over here, and for the first time.... Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Sure is possible. You'll need however to employ some conventions so the code can be generic. [See it live](https://ideone.com/blSEj5).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Flyable{
  int loadConcreteData(){
    cout << "Flyable\n"; return 0;
  }
};

struct Drivable{
  int loadConcreteData(){
     cout << "Drivable\n"; return 0;
  }
};

class Object{
  virtual void loadData(){
  }
};

template<class ...CS>
struct ConcreteLoader : Object, CS... {
    void loadData() override {
        int load[] = {
            this->CS::loadConcreteData()...
        };
    }
};

class FlyingCar : public ConcreteLoader<Flyable,Drivable>{
};

int main() {
    FlyingCar fc;
    fc.loadData();
    return 0;
}
```

Changes that need mentioning:

1. The return type of each concrete `Load` function had to be changed. This is to facilitate the "array trick" in expanding the parameter pack.
2. The names of all the load functions are the same, again for the same reason.

Reason (1) may become obsolete once c++17 and fold expressions roll out.

Comment: I'd suggest to provide code that at least compiles, your methods done return it's..

Comment: @OlegBogdanov, oh it doesn't compile? I suppose the live example is a lie

Comment: OK, sorry, it compiles but has some UBs

Comment: @OlegBogdanov don't keep us guessing, what's the UB?

Comment: Omitting the return statement in a non-void function [Except main()] and using the returned value yields Undefined Behaviour. Right?

Comment: @OlegBogdanov, fine, fixed. Wasn't pertinent to solution so I overlooked it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: great answer... but i am unable to understand what `int load[] = {           this->CS::loadConcreteData()...};` is?

Comment: @Hummingbird -- Broadly, a parameter pack expansion is only possible in a context the requires comma separated lists. I.e. arrays, function calls/definitions and template instantiation. The dummy array creates such a context.

Comment: @StoryTeller Great answer! couldn't `int load[] = { this->CS::loadConcreteData()...};` be replaced with `int load[] = { (this->CS::loadConcreteData(), 0)... };` to make it work without dummy function result?

Comment: @W.F. Sure could. I learned it today from **krzaq**, you definitely should check out his answer, it's much more thorough.

Comment: @StoryTeller also some time ago someone told me that the `(this->CS::loadConcreteData(), 0)...` might be an extension of compiler and I wasn't sure - that's why the comment was in asking tone... :)

Comment: @W.F. you might want to cast to `void`, otherwise it can break for pathological cases (where `loadConcreteData` returns a type that overloads `operator,`)

Comment: @krzaq true haven't thought about it - thank you! so - it is not a compiler extension right?

Comment: @W.F. Nope. Just a regular employment of the builtin comma operator inside parenthesis.

Comment: @StoryTeller I also though so but not very good in seeking over standard to be sure... :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you explain in more detail please ? Especially how loadData() in concreteLoader works... I read the comments, but its something I have never seen before....

Comment: What is this "array trick" called ? Where can I read more about it ? Is there a technical name for it ?